# Class Field Theory Video Lectures

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, online-resources, class-field-theory

Are there any good video lectures online discussing algebraic number theory, class field theory, or related topics? Something on the level of the book of Neukirch or Cassels and Frohlich would be preferred.

Comment: If you search for videos with the “secret code” теория полей классов, then you’ll find videos on class field theory, but unless you already knew that code you probably will not get much out of the videos.

Comment: Are there ones not taught in Russian?

Answer (score 5):

There are videos from the [2018 edition](https://ctnt-summer.math.uconn.edu/schedules-and-abstracts-2018/) of the Connecticut Summer School in Number Theory, featuring a lecture series (Minicourse A) by Liang Xiao on "Basic Algebraic Number Theory". Lecture notes and exercises are available at the page linked above, while the video recording is on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3SJON86hcU). You could also keep an eye on the [2020 edition](https://ctnt-summer.math.uconn.edu/schedules-and-abstracts-2020-online/), which features more minicourses on Number Theory. I hope this is helpful, while answering only part of your question.

Comment: The 2020 videos are already posted. There were no lecture courses on class field theory in that summer school in 2018 or 2020. There was a lecture course on algebraic number theory in 2018 by Liang Xiao.

Comment: @KCd, indeed I only picked up the algebraic number theory part of the question. Unfortunately I am not aware of video lectures on class field theory.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1420488)

Comment: @MattSamuel, many thanks for your comments. I edited my post making it clear that I am only focusing on number theory and not class field theory. I also included the direct link to the Youtube video, hoping to provide some redundancy in case the school's web page goes down at some point.

Comment: Hi Aurelio, by an abuse of the notification system, I would like to notify you about this meta discussion: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32110/61691 In short, I think your edit was not correct. Also, I think it would have been better to first ask in the comments when you think there is something wrong.

Comment: Hi @azimut. Many thanks for your message and apologies for the wrong edit. Your comment above is the only notification I received, and I am sorry that your previous attempts at pinging me did not work. I answered in the meta discussion you linked.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking myself for some video lectures and just found this course https://kskedlaya.org/math204b-win21/ by Kedlaya which looks promising.